# Using session in web.py, session does not work as documented

Tags: python, session, web.py

I'm writing a website by using web.py, when i use session i am confused, it does not work as expected. Here is my code:

```
#encoding=utf-8
#!/usr/bin/env python

import web

urls = (
        '/', 'Index',
    )


app = web.application(urls, globals())

if web.config.get('_session') is None:
    store = web.session.DiskStore('sessions')
    session = web.session.Session(app,store,initializer={'count': 0})
    web.config._session = session
else:
    session = web.config._session

render = web.template.render('templates', base='base')


class Index:
    def GET(self):
        print session.count
        print session.get('count')
        #print session['count']

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

The Question is the usages of session.count and session['count'] will raise errors(AttributeError: 'ThreadedDict' object has no attribute 'count').

However, The code above just looks like as same as the office document [Sessions In Web.py](http://webpy.org/cookbook/sessions)
Why it does not work?

Please Help!

Comment: platform: mac os x, web.py: 0.37

Comment: Can you post all of your code? This runs on my computer, with a main routine.

Comment: Ok, that's all of the content as i just want to test how to set and get session values. session.count or session.get('count') or session['count']?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you call `app = web.application(urls, globals())` get rid of the one in main, and everything works fine:

```
#encoding=utf-8
#!/usr/bin/env python

import web

urls = (
        '/', 'Index',
    )


app = web.application(urls, globals())

if web.config.get('_session') is None:
    store = web.session.DiskStore('sessions')
    session = web.session.Session(app,store,initializer={'count': 0})
    web.config._session = session
else:
    session = web.config._session

render = web.template.render('templates', base='base')


class Index:
    def GET(self):
        print session.count
        print session.get('count')
        #print session['count']

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```